# Full page with nested flexbox and scrolling

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I'm trying to do what I thought was a fairly standard sort of full-screen layout using flexbox, but it's not behaving the way I want.  My goals are:

- Auto sizing of topbar/footer height and sidebar width (size to content, not fixed size)
- Topbar/footer take full width and never scroll
- Sidebar takes full height but if contents are larger can vertically scroll only
- Content takes leftover width/height but if contents are larger can scroll both ways
- Sidebar/Content scroll independently of each other (and hide scrollbars when not needed)
- Main content area will *usually* appear as regular doc with scrollbar, but sometimes I want it to also have some nested sidebars with a remaining-height scrolling subpanel.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.page {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.topbar {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.vcontainer {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 0;
}

.sidebar {
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.footer {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <nav class="topbar">
    top bar
  </nav>
  <div class="vcontainer">
    <nav class="sidebar">
      side<br/>side<br/>side
    </nav>
    <main class="content">
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
    </main>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">
    footer
  </footer>
</div>
```

The above works fine for the full doc scrolling variant (although the magic was adding the `min-height` to `vcontainer`; it didn't work prior to that) -- the blue area takes the remaining space and is scrollable if the content gets too long.

Without changing the outer styling (or at least not changing it in a way that breaks the above scenario), I want to be able to *sometimes* put in some `content` that essentially has an additional dynamic-height topbar and a scrolling subsection that doesn't trigger the main content scrollbar.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.page {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.topbar {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.vcontainer {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 0;
}

.sidebar {
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.footer {
  background-color: pink;
}

.contentcontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 0;
}

.contentsub {
  margin: 1rem;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <nav class="topbar">
    top bar
  </nav>
  <div class="vcontainer">
    <nav class="sidebar">
      side<br/>side<br/>side
    </nav>
    <main class="content">
      <div class="contentcontainer">
        <div>
          some additional heading content
        </div>
        <div class="contentsub">
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          some additional footer content
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">
    footer
  </footer>
</div>
```

What I'm wanting is for the blue area to not have a scrollbar in this case, but instead for the orange area to be scrollable, surrounded by the extra header/footer and sized to fill the leftover space.  Ideally, this should work even if `contentsub` isn't a direct child of the `contentcontainer` but there's more wrapping elements and borders etc before getting to the scrollable element.  I would prefer a solution that's "pure flexbox", but if there's a better way to do it then I'm all ears.  I do want to avoid using javascript, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this after a bit of tweaking:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.page {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.topbar {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.vcontainer {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 0;
}

.sidebar {
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.footer {
  background-color: pink;
}

.contentcontainer {
  height: 100%;
}

.contentsub {
  max-height: max(40%, 2rem);
  margin: 1rem;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <nav class="topbar">
    top bar
  </nav>
  <div class="vcontainer">
    <nav class="sidebar">
      side<br/>side<br/>side
    </nav>
    <main class="content">
      <div class="contentcontainer">
        <div>
          some additional heading content
        </div>
        <div class="contentsub">
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
          <p>some actual content</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          some additional footer content
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">
    footer
  </footer>
</div>
```

Grid approach:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body,
.page {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.topbar {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: pink;
}

.contentsub {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 1rem;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: orange;
}

@media (min-width: 30rem) {
  .page {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "header header" "sidebar content" "footer footer";
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 9fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <header class="topbar">
    top bar
  </header>
  <aside class="sidebar">
    side<br/>side<br/>side
  </aside>
  <main class="content">
    <div>
      some additional heading content
    </div>
    <div class="contentsub">
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
      <p>some actual content</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      some additional footer content
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer class="footer">
    footer
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: The orange area isn't taking the full remaining height -- not even in the mini preview and especially not in the full page view.

Comment: @Miral Fixed, I flexed the parent columnwise and let contentsub grow. Please try and be more polite with your comments in the future, you are getting help for free and maybe your question isn't clear enough, so assume good faith from those answering.

Comment: That seems to work, thanks.  There was nothing impolite in my original comment, though.  Having said that, I'm still hoping that there's some alternative flexbox solution; I'm using Bootstrap 5 which seems to prefer flexbox over grid for whatever reason.

Comment: Actually, looking at your code more closely, it does appear to only be using flexbox within the `content` panel at least.  Could you explain why this works and the nested flexbox didn't seem to?  It's quite mystifying to me.

Comment: Oh, wait, this still doesn't quite work.  The yellow sidebar is changing size with the viewport, not being sized strictly according to its content as in the original.

Comment: Looks like changing it to `grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;` fixes that.

Comment: For the record, I had some additional problems getting this to work when there were some additional wrapping elements around `contentsub`.  The trick was to ensure that it used flexbox all the way down, and that `contentsub` itself has `flex-basis: 0`.